# CSS border color

Tags: html, css

How do I make the border of my header have the same color as my header? When I ran my code, the border of the header has the HTML background color. How do I make it so that the background color of the header fills the edge of the page?

```css
header {
  background-color: #3AAFA9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="home">Hi</h1>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: @AndyRay I think that is a poor example for a duplicate. YOur duplicate is soley caused by a typo ( using `#body` instead of `body` as selector).

Comment: The `white-space` is caused by the default body margin. You can remove it by using: `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score -2):

You can reset the margin of all elements which are applied differently in different browsers. If you're still wondering why we need it, you can check [this article](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

```css
* {
   margin: 0; /*Reset margin*/
}

header {
  background-color: #3AAFA9;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="home">Hi</h1>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
```